# Show that the number of steps of the Euclidean algorithm is less than $2\log_2{b}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the number of steps of the Euclidean algorithm is smaller than $2\log_2{b}$ where $b\ge a$. **Before** you dismiss the question as a copy, I have crucial questions, not answered in another copies, that I really need to know: when\where does the transition between number of repetitions of a given operation and $\log$ function occurs? How does it occur? I know that the number of steps in Euclidean algorithm is at most $\log a+\log b$, but why?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Find the worst case. Hint: with [Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), there will be only subtractions, no actual division. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Algorithmic_efficiency).

Comment: The worst case scenario is the longest proccess possible?

Comment: Yes. See for example [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_complexity), and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case).